# python: what is the ~ operator functionallity within python3

Tags: python

I have been looking through some examples of code in python 3 and i have never seen anything like the
`~` operator used before.

Here is the snippet of code:

```
array[i][~i] for i in range(0, 3)
```

My first guess was it reverses like the value of i to start so on first iteration `[i]` would be 0 but `[~i]` would be 2 would i be correct in saying that?

Any explanations or documentation to read would be appreciated as i tried to look for information on it but couldn't find anything.

Comment: That is the bit-wise not operator. `~x` usually equals `-x - 1` for small x

Comment: Define "small"; it holds for all `int` values in Python.